# Wkhtmltopdf print in duplex

Tags: duplex, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

Somebody know way to print in **duplex**. So i have problem, because i have summary file where is a lot of statements. I have to print in duplex and problem is with print it, because sometimes statements have odd numer page and last page is print on first page next statement.

Have somebody any idea.
Thanks!

Comment: great question, I have the same problem as well.